# Problema con el método toUpperCase()

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
function accum(s) {
    let resultado = "";
    let cadenaAgregar = "";

    s.split("").forEach((item, i) => {
        cadenaAgregar += item.repeat(i + 1);
        cadenaAgregar[0].toUpperCase();
        resultado += cadenaAgregar;
        cadenaAgregar = "";
    });

    return resultado;
}

console.log(accum("abcd"));
```

Se supone que antes de agregarse la cadena a la variable 'resultado' la primera letra se convierta en mayúscula pero esto no funciona, agradecería saber por qué sucede esto y qué debería hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

En la línea donde quieres cambiar la primera letra a mayúscula no la asignas a nada

```
cadenaAgregar[0].toUpperCase();
```

Por lo tanto es como si no existiera

Puedes asignar la conversión a la misma variable `cadenaAgregar`:

```
cadenaAgregar = cadenaAgregar[0].toUpperCase()
```

Pero eso eliminaría el resto de la cadena, para incluirlo puedes utilizar [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```
cadenaAgregar = cadenaAgregar[0].toUpperCase() + cadenaAgregar.slice(1);
```

Otra opción sería utilizar `charAt()` con `slice()`

```
cadenaAgregar = cadenaAgregar.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cadenaAgregar.slice(1);
```

Ejemplo completo:

```js
function accum(s) {
    let resultado = "";
    let cadenaAgregar = "";

    s.split("").forEach((item, i) => {
        cadenaAgregar += item.repeat(i + 1);
        cadenaAgregar = cadenaAgregar[0].toUpperCase() + cadenaAgregar.slice(1);
        resultado += cadenaAgregar;
        cadenaAgregar = "";
    });

    return resultado;
}

console.log(accum('prueba'))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
PRrUuuEeeeBbbbbAaaaaa
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: No hay de que, recuerda siempre revisar si una función modifica el objeto original o retorna uno nuevo, en este caso `toUpperCase` retorna el `string` en mayúsculas, pero no modifica el `string` original.